# facebook graph api: /me OAuthException (c#)

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + app.AccessToken);
```

My accesstoken works when im fetching other stuff from the graph api. But when i try to get info about the current user i get the errormessage:

```
{
"error": {
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."
}
}
```

The user has connected to my app on the page. Did i miss something? All i need is his userID. Thanks

Comment: how you get the value from app.AccessToken? Is this logic correct. Seems your access token isn't valid

Comment: have you used a token with the appropriate access permissions? There is a seperate access permission for "details about me"

Answer (score 2):

access token expire.  you need to ensure that the access token you have is valid.  see the https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500.